# Javascript property as reference to other object's property

Tags: javascript, object, reference

Is there a way to assign properties of one object as references to the properties of another, and do so dynamically?  Note that in the for loop, I've skipped any property that has the same name as the second object.  I'm working on a framework that will cache JSON as objects with behaviors and allow ORM kind of behavior, where I can grab cached objects and collections as properties of other cached objects.  I need to skip certain properties to avoid circular reference.

```
var obj1 = {
    prop1: "hey",
    obj2:"you",
    prop2: "come over here"
}

var obj2 = {}

for(var prop in obj1){
    if(prop != 'obj2'){
        obj2[prop] = obj1[prop];
    }
}
console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);

obj1.prop2 = "come on, man";

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
//obj1 is unchanged in output.  I would like to be able to update it by mutating obj2's properties
```

fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/6ncasLb0/1/

If this is not possible, is it possible to remove or mutate a property of a reference without mutating the original object?  I know, probably not.  Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: No, that is not possible. You might be able to use [`Object.observe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) once it becomes more widely available. But since it's ES7, that will probably still take a while.

Comment: @FelixKling what if we use setters to synchronize?

Comment: @zerkms: I guess that could work as long as defining the property as a setter is a possibility at all. However, maybe there is a better solution altogether for the OP's use case.

Comment: Well, fortunately for all of us, the actual objects in the framework DO have setters using some prototypal inheritance and voodoo.  The thing is, this stuff is actually being called by a cache manager within a lazy loaded branch of a getter.  I'll see if I can work around the problem using the setters.  Basically, I need SOME of the properties to be references while having the NULL ones not overwrite the same properties of the cached objects.  Maybe I should rethink the architecture, but this whole thing is so close to working....

Comment: I think getters need to be involved too, so that accessing a property of one object returns the value of a property on some other object.

Comment: There really isn't a simple way to reference one objects property as a property of another object?  Javascript, you crazy.  You can never intuitively know what will be a "reference" and what will be a "value"

Answer (score 2):

I guess the closest you can get to it, is to make sure the property you are changing it the same property you are getting on both objects, so you would need to do some work to make sure they "know" each other when they are instantiated (eg, clone from the original object)

As an example, you could use a simplified model like this, any properties marked in its creation would also update the original object, though new properties defined on the object should be fine). Note that enumrating and just referencing the properties wouldn't work, at least not with strings (objects would change when copied from 1 object to another)

```js
;
(function(namespace) {
  function addProperty(obj, property, valueholder) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, property, {
      get: function() {
        return valueholder[property];
      },
      set: function(val) {
        valueholder[property] = val;
      },
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: false
    });
  }

  var model = namespace.model || function(options) {
    if (typeof options === 'undefined') {
      options = {};
    }
    var propHolder = options.container || {},
      prop;
    if (typeof options.props != null) {
      for (prop in options.props) {
        if (options.props.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          addProperty(this, prop, propHolder);
          propHolder[prop] = options.props[prop];
        }
      }
    };

    namespace.model.prototype.clone = function() {
      var options = {
          props: {},
          container: propHolder
        },
        prop;
      for (prop in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          options.props[prop] = this[prop];
        }
      }
      return new namespace.model(options);
    };

    namespace.model.prototype.toString = function() {
      var prop, msg, props = [];
      for (prop in propHolder) {
        if (propHolder.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          props.push(prop + ': "' + this[prop].toString() + '"');
        }
      }
      return '[Model] {' + props.join(', ') + '}';
    }

    return this;
  };

  namespace.model = model;
}(window));

var obj1 = new model({
  props: {
    prop2: "come over here"
  }
});
obj1.prop1 = 'Hey';
obj1.obj2 = 'You';
obj1.test = {
  a: 10
};

var obj2 = obj1.clone();

console.log('-- before changes --');
console.log(obj1.toString());
console.log(obj2.toString());

obj2.prop2 = "come on, man";
obj2.prop1 = "won't change";
obj2.obj2 = "also not";
obj2.test.b = "both have this now";

console.log('-- after changes --');
console.log(obj1.toString());
console.log(obj2.toString());

console.log(obj1.test);
console.log(obj2.test);
```

Comment: Interesting.  I'll give it a try and let you know, as it will require a refactor of all my classes.